# igraph/visNetwork with R: How to disable forward linking?

Tags: r, igraph, visnetwork

The following code produces a nice network diagram:

```
library(igraph);library(visNetwork);library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
nnodes <- 10
nnedges <- 20

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:nnodes)
edges <- data.frame(from = sample(1:nnodes, nnedges, replace = T),
                    to = sample(1:nnodes, nnedges, replace = T))

visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle") %>%
  visNodes(shape="circle") %>% 
  visOptions(highlightNearest = list(enabled = T, hover = T), nodesIdSelection = T)
```

My question is: How can I disable that edges that leave from a neighboring node are displayed as well (e.g. when node 8 is selected, I don't want the edge from 3 to 9 to be shown).

Edit: Libraries added, thx for poining that out

[image]
[image]

Comment: Since your code uses both `visNetwork` and `dplyr` it would be helpful for you to include the library statements for those too.

Comment: [maybe related](https://github.com/datastorm-open/visNetwork/issues/160)

Comment: Does the `highlightNearest` option `algorithm = "hierarchical"` what you are looking for?

Comment: This might helps: `visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle") %>% visNodes(shape="circle") %>% visOptions(nodesIdSelection = T) %>%  visInteraction(hover = T)` with `nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:nnodes, label = 1:nnodes)`. It correctly highlights the nodes but `hideColor`  (grey) is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Using the comment from Djack and wici, I achieved the following solution:

```
library(igraph);library(visNetwork);library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
nnodes <- 10
nnedges <- 20

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:nnodes, label = 1:nnodes)
edges <- data.frame(from = sample(1:nnodes, nnedges, replace = T),
                    to = sample(1:nnodes, nnedges, replace = T))

visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% 
  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle") %>% 
  visNodes(shape="circle") %>% 
  visOptions(highlightNearest = list(enabled = T, hover = T, algorithm="hierarchical"),nodesIdSelection = T) %>% 
  visInteraction(hover = T)
```

I hope, thats what you're looking for.